# Reprojecting xy tiles from mercator to Gauß-Krueger in ubuntu terminal?

Tags: coordinate-system, tiles, mbtiles, mercator

I have exported a map from tilemill as mbtiles and converted them to xyz tiles with help of [mbutil](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil). The tiles should be used (for learning purpose) with mod_tile or GeoServer and displayed in OpenLayers.

in OpenLayers already exists a bunch of layers using the gauß-krüger projection.

Do you know a program which runs under ubuntu-terminal to reproject these tiles from Mercator to Gauß-Krüger projection to have only one used projection?

Inspecting a raster tile with [gdalinfo](http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html) gives me following info:

```
Driver: PNG/Portable Network Graphics
Files: /Users/srv/Desktop/tiles/11/586/784.png
Size is 256, 256
Coordinate System is `'
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  256.0)
Upper Right (  256.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  256.0,  256.0)
Center      (  128.0,  128.0)
Band 1 Block=256x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
Image Structure Metadata:
NBITS=1
Color Table (RGB with 1 entries)
0: 245,253,240,255
```

Comment: The tiles aren't really in Mercator. They're in an almost-Mercator ("web Mercator"). Translating individual tiles doesn't make a lot of sense though - as you've seen, they're just unreferenced pictures and the tile schema makes the projection. Can you tell us what you're trying to do (in the end - the "why" of the reprojection) and we might be able to help to achieve that.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer! I´ve edited my question. it´s more a question of understanding as I´m just starting with all this …

Comment: So you want to use your newly created tiles as basemap to some data you already have (e.g. instead of using google maps or bing or whatever is the current basemap)?

Comment: exactly! the current basemap is osm, but I´ve styled it with tilemill and want to use this as basemap.

Comment: Just keep doing the reprojection on the client. You're already doing this with OSM, so just do it with your tiles instead.